# Is there an Instruments API?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, instruments

Is it possible to setup an Instruments run programmatically from my code? For instance, I'd like to structure my code something like this where `startTrace` might setup a specific probe for the current thread and start recording while `stopTrace` would stop recording. I would be writing the content of those routines using the Instruments API that is the subject of this question.

```
-(void)myInterestingMethod
{
    [self startTrace];

    // do something interesting and performance critical

    [self stopTrace];
}
```

If the above isn't available, is setting up my own DTrace probe a viable alternative?

Comment: libdtrace could be an option but I’m not sure the API is documented.

Comment: We can now use "points of interest". See http://stackoverflow.com/a/39416673/1271826.

Answer (score 5):

Doesn't look like there's anything straight-forward, but there is an `instruments` command-line tool. Here's some quick+dirty code that will invoke it and sample CPU usage for the calling process

```
static void sampleMe() {
    // instruments -t '/Developer/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/Resources/templates/CPU Sampler.tracetemplate' -p 26838 -l 5000

    NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
    [task setLaunchPath:@"/usr/bin/instruments"];
    [task setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                        @"-t",
                        @"/Developer/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/Resources/templates/CPU Sampler.tracetemplate",
                        @"-p",
                        [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", getpid()],
                        @"-l",
                        @"5000",
                        nil]];
    [task setCurrentDirectoryPath:NSHomeDirectory()];
    [task setStandardInput:[NSPipe pipe]];
    [task setStandardOutput:[NSPipe pipe]];
    [task setStandardError:[NSPipe pipe]];
    [task launch];
    // purposely leak everything since I can't be bothered to figure out lifetimes
}
```

After invocation a file named `instrumentscli0.trace` will be in your home directory.

**Update:** Instruments 4.0 offers [DTSendSignalFlag](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/AnalysisTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewInstruments/NewFeatures40/NewFeatures40.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010950-CH2-SW16) in the DTPerformanceSession for iOS apps.

Comment: +1 for "// purposely leak everything since I can't be bothered to figure out lifetimes"

Comment: Note: It appears that DTPerformanceSession only works on the simulator.  This is not useful for me because I only care about the device's performance profile.