# How to identify key events in Xcode Instruments?

Tags: xcode-instruments, dtsignalflag

There used to be a nice tool, `DTSendSignalFlag`, part of the `DTPerformanceSession` framework, by which you could programmatically insert flags into Instruments. ([Xcode Instruments trace comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20269630/xcode-instruments-trace-comparison) explains how we used this macOS diagnostic tool in iOS targets). This feature stopped working in iOS 7.

Has anyone succeeded in getting `DTSendSignalFlag` to work in iOS 7? Signal flags are (were?) a useful way to programmatically post flags in Instruments via code (really helpful when diagnosing complicated apps in Instruments), but I am not seeing my programmatically created flags in Instruments when I run on the iOS 7 simulator (but it works when I have Xcode 5 build for the iOS 6 simulator).

Needless to say, I am also looking for a similar tool for macOS targets, too.

Comment: I can't find any mention of this, or a replacement if its gone. Would love to be able to get something like this working.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Rather than using flags, we can now use programmatically inserted signposts which are captured in Instruments’ “Points of Interest” tool.

In iOS 15 and macOS 12, we can use [`OSSignposter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/ossignposter/). For example, in Swift:

- Import the unified logging framework:

  ```swift
  import os.signpost
  ```
- Create an `OSSignposter` for points of interest:

  ```swift
  private let pointsOfInterest = OSSignposter(subsystem: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!, category: .pointsOfInterest)
  ```
- When you want to start a points of interest range, you can “begin” an interval:

  ```swift
  let id = pointsOfInterest.makeSignpostID()
  let state = pointsOfInterest.beginInterval("Download", id: id, "\(index)")
  ```
- When you want to end a points of interest range, you can “end” it:

  ```swift
  pointsOfInterest.endInterval(#function, state)
  ```
- If you’re not interested in a range of time, but rather a single signpost, you can just emit an event:

  ```swift
  pointsOfInterest.emitEvent("Done")
  ```

If you need to support older OS versions, in iOS 13 and macOS 10.15, we can use `os_signpost` as shown in WWC 2019’s [Getting Started with Instruments](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/411/?time=1234).

For example, in Swift:

- Import the unified logging framework:

  ```swift
  import os.signpost
  ```
- Create an `OSLog` for points of interest:

  ```swift
  private let pointsOfInterest = OSLog(subsystem: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!, category: .pointsOfInterest)
  ```
- When you want to start a points of interest range, you can `.begin` a point of interest:

  ```swift
  let id = OSSignpostID(log: pointsOfInterest)
  os_signpost(.begin, log: pointsOfInterest, name: "Download", signpostID: id, "Download %d", index)
  ```
- When you want to end a points of interest range, you can `.end` it:

  ```swift
  os_signpost(.end, log: pointsOfInterest, name: "Download", signpostID: id, "Download %d", index)
  ```
- If you’re not interested in a range of time, but rather a single signpost, you can just post an `.event`:

  ```swift
  os_signpost(.event, log: pointsOfInterest, name: "Done", "All done")
  ```

Or in Objective-C:

- Import the unified logging signposts framework:

  ```objectivec
  @import os.signpost;
  ```
- Create an `OSLog` for points of interest:

  ```objectivec
  os_log_t log = os_log_create("ViewController", OS_LOG_CATEGORY_POINTS_OF_INTEREST);
  ```
- When you want to start a points of interest range, you can `.begin` a point of interest:

  ```objectivec
  os_signpost_id_t identifier = os_signpost_id_generate(log);
  os_signpost_interval_begin(log, identifier, "Download", "Started %d", index);
  ```
- When you want to end a points of interest range, you can `.end` it:

  ```objectivec
  os_signpost_interval_end(log, identifier, "Download", "Finished %d", index);
  ```
- If you’re not interested in a range of time, but rather a single signpost, you can just post an `.event`:

  ```objectivec
  os_signpost_event_emit(log, OS_SIGNPOST_ID_EXCLUSIVE, "Done");
  ```

Anyway, the “Points of Interest” instrument can now graphically represent a series of downloads and parse operations (each queue constrained to two concurrent operations per queue) in Instruments:

[image]

Note that the `name` values (one set I used the name `Download` and the other I used `Parse`) are nicely separated into different swim-lanes in the Points of Interest tool. And because I used the optional format strings, I can actually see messages where I can clearly correlate each download and parse operation to a specific task in my app.

Above I have used the optional `OSSignpostID` parameters because I had multiple ranges overlapping and I wanted to avoid any confusion associating a particular `.end` with the corresponding `.begin`. If you either aren’t using points of interest ranges or you don’t have overlapping ranges, you technically don’t need to use this optional parameter if no possible ambiguity is possible. (Even if you use these signpost identifiers, make sure that the `name` of the associated `.begin` and `.end` signposts also match, or else Instruments won’t identify them as the start and end of the same point of interest range, even with the same signpost id.)

Anyway, now that you have the “Points of Interest” tool populated with information, you can double-click on a range to select it, or triple-click on it to also set your inspection range.

---

In iOS 10 and macOS 10.12, we used `kdebug_signpost`. This was illustrated in WWDC 2016 video [System Trace in Depth](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/411/). (Unfortunately, this video is no longer available.)

For those processes that take a discrete amount of time, we can use `kdebug_signpost_start` and `kdebug_signpost_end`. For example:

```swift
kdebug_signpost_start(SignPostCode.download.rawValue, UInt(index), 0, 0, SignPostColor.orange.rawValue)
performDownload {
    kdebug_signpost_end(SignPostCode.download.rawValue, UInt(index), 0, 0, SignPostColor.orange.rawValue)
}
```

To mark a single moment in time, we can just use `kdebug_signpost`:

```swift
kdebug_signpost(SignPostCode.done.rawValue, 0, 0, 0, SignPostColor.red.rawValue)
```

The first parameter is just some unique numeric code that corresponds to a “signpost code name” that we will use in Instruments. You can use whatever values you want (between 0 and 16383), but I use something that designates the type of task:

```swift
enum SignPostCode: UInt32 {   // some custom constants that I'll reference in Instruments
    case download = 0
    case parse = 1
    case done = 2
}
```

The rest of the parameters can be whatever `UInt` values you want, but in my example, I will use the second parameter as a unique identifier to match up repeated `start` and `end` calls and I will use the last parameter to color code my regions in Instruments:

```swift
enum SignPostColor: UInt {    // standard color scheme for signposts in Instruments
    case blue = 0
    case green = 1
    case purple = 2
    case orange = 3
    case red = 4
}
```

Having done this, you can then profile the app in Instruments, click on the “+” button on the right side of the Instruments toolbar, and add “Points of Interest”. By configuring the “Signpost Code Names” to match the numeric values I passed as the first parameter to my signposts, Instruments will actually translate those codes for me. Once I profile the app and I now have my points of interest clearly highlighted for me:

[image]

In this snapshot, I profiled seven download operations (in orange) and seven parse operations (in green), constrained to two at a time, respectively. And when they were done, I posted a single “done” signpost (pin red). But the details of this demo app are not critical, but rather this just illustrates how single signposts and start/end signposts are rendered in Instruments’ “Points of Interest”.

The main issue is that I now have clear correspondence between events in my code and what I see in Instruments. And I can <kbd>control</kbd>-click on an entry in the list of signpost ranges and tell Instruments to “Set time filter”, if I want, so that when I go back to my other instruments (allocations or time profiler or whatever), the inspection range is filtered down to the relevant points of interest in my app.

---

Note, the above is Swift. In Objective-C, the `kdebug_signpost` API is similar, but you have to include:

```objectivec
#import <sys/kdebug_signpost.h>
```

Obviously, how you define your enumerations for your codes will change, too.

Note, this `kdebug_signpost` API was introduced in iOS 10/macOS 10.12. The headers tell us that earlier OS versions could use `syscall`:

> In previous versions of the operating system, applications could use:
>
> ```
> syscall(SYS_kdebug_trace, APPSDBG_CODE(DBG_MACH_CHUD, <your event code>) | DBG_FUNC_<type>, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4);
> ```
>
> to record events that would be displayed by Instruments. `syscall(2)` is now deprecated and this interface replaces the above call.

Note: If you find yourself having to use `syscall` on an earlier OS version, you will have to import `<sys/kdebug.h>`:

```objectivec
#import <sys/kdebug.h>
```

Also, I was not able to find a declaration of `SYS_kdebug_trace` in any of the headers, but stumbled across a reference online that said that this value is `180`, which I empirically verified:

```objectivec
#ifndef SYS_kdebug_trace
#define SYS_kdebug_trace 180
#endif
```

Comment: Is there a way to save/apply commonly used sign post configuration in Instruments (to assist in debugging several apps that share a common code base, for instance)?  Is there any way to monitor signpost events directly using dtrace (and not use Instruments)?  Great answer, btw!

Comment: @lilinjn - Use "Save As Template..." option in Instruments' "File" menu. Then, the next time you run Instruments, rather than picking one of the standard tools, click on "Custom", and you'll see your saved template there. Re dtrace, I don't know.

Comment: For completeness --  I believe you can use dtrace's ability to monitor syscalls and their arguments, plus a little reverse engineering implied by the  legacy support information  : `syscall(SYS_kdebug_trace, APPSDBG_CODE(DBG_MACH_CHUD, <your event code>)...` to get access to signpost events without Instruments (but I have not worked out the details).  Hopefully these two extra pieces of info will make an excellent answer even better.  Thanks!

Comment: Any ideas on how to avoid 'conflicts' on singpost codes between several libraries that all use signposts?

Comment: @Black_Ivory_86 - You're obviously constrained here, but if it's colliding with your codes, you'll just have to alter what values you use. Note that if your problem is with start/end signposts, you can minimize mismatching start/end signpost errors by going to the options for "Points of Interest", which let you specify whether you match up signposts by merely by code, or by code and first argument, or by code and thread.

Comment: I can't get the pre-Sierra version using syscall to work, perhaps because the pre-Sierra Instruments I'm using doesn't have "Points of Interest".

Comment: Worked nicely. One thing which seems omitted in the answer is that you need this #import line to use these functions:
#import <sys/kdebug_signpost.h>

Comment: Thanks, Rob! I don't see the signpost intervals in the Points of Interest Instrument, but have to add the os_signpost instrument (click the + button top right). I can't seem to see signpost events, though.

Comment: For anyone having trouble finding the Objective-C variants, here's a nice article from the good people at PSPDFKit with both Swift and ObjC code: https://pspdfkit.com/blog/2018/using-signposts-for-performance-tuning-on-ios/

Comment: Can I control the colors in the new API? I really miss that... I know it does grouping for me, but I can not assign group names dynamically - what kind of backward API is that...

Comment: apologies. my mistake.

Comment: FWIW, if anyone is interested in a custom Instruments’ tool that provides different color coding for intervals, see https://github.com/robertmryan/CustomPointsOfInterest.

Comment: If only analyzing network activity, you can use [Analyze HTTP traffic in Instruments](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10212/), without delving into manual signpost in “points of interest” at all.

Answer (score 2):

**2019**

Signpost has been updated with an easier API. Video here (`Time: 20:40`)

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/411/

See **Debugging CPU Performance** in Apple logging documentation.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logging