# Is it possible to add a marker to instruments from code?

Tags: ios, xcode, instruments, xcode-instruments

I would like add some kind of marker or even force instruments to pause when execution reaches a specific line in the code. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes with DTrace, you can set flags with code. See this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20272256/451475). It seems this is broken in iOS7 simulator, possibly fixed in iOS8. I used this on OSX.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sign_posts using Xcode's new `kdebug_signpost` command. See the SO post at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39416673/1179897