# How to constrain concurrency (like `maxConcurrentOperationCount`) with Swift Concurrency?

Tags: swift, async-await, swift-concurrency

I am trying to perform a series of network requests and would like to limit the number of concurrent tasks in the new Swift Concurrency system. With operation queues we would use [`maxConcurrentOperationCount`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operationqueue/1414982-maxconcurrentoperationcount/). In Combine, [`flatMap(maxPublishers:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publishers/last/flatmap(maxpublishers:_:)-2uxs5/). What is the equivalent in the new Swift Concurrency system?

E.g., it is not terribly relevant, but consider:

```swift
func downloadAll() async throws {
    try await withThrowingTaskGroup(of: Void.self) { group in
        for index in 0..<20 {
            group.addTask { try await self.download(index) }
        }

        try await group.waitForAll()
    }
}
```

That results in all the requests running concurrently:

[image]

The fact that `URLSession` is not honoring `httpMaximumConnectionsPerHost` is interesting, but not the salient issue here. I am looking for, more generally, how to constrain the degree of concurrency in a series of asynchronous tasks running in parallel.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

One can insert a [`group.next()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/throwingtaskgroup/3814935-next) call inside the loop after reaching a certain count, e.g.:

```swift
func downloadAll() async throws {
    try await withThrowingTaskGroup(of: Void.self) { group in
        for index in 0..<20 {
            if index >= 6 { try await group.next() }
            group.addTask { try await self.download(index) }
        }

        try await group.waitForAll()
    }
}
```

That results in no more than six at a time:

[image]

---

For the sake of completeness, I should note that in WWDC 2023 [Beyond the basics of structured concurrency](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10170?time=637), Apple suggests an alternative pattern:

```swift
withTaskGroup(of: Something.self) { group in
    for _ in 0 ..< maxConcurrentTasks {
        group.addTask { … }
    }
    while let <partial result> = await group.next() {
        if !shouldStop {
            group.addTask { … }
        }
    }
}
```

Which, in this example, might translate to:

```swift
func downloadAll() async throws {
    try await withThrowingTaskGroup(of: Void.self) { group in
        for index in 0..<6 {
            group.addTask { try await self.download(index) }
        }
        var index = 6
        while try await group.next() != nil {
            if index < 20 {
                group.addTask { [index] in try await self.download(index) }
            }
            index += 1
        }
    }
}
```

Yielding (in Instruments):

[image]

The idea is very similar, namely that you `group.addTask {…}` up to the max desired concurrency, but then `group.next()` before adding each subsequent task. It is another way to crack the nut.

Comment: How might I open the network timeline (pictured) from Xcode? (Also, super clean solution, thanks for posting!)

Comment: @emehex - That happens to be a screen snapshot from [Charles Proxy](https://charlesproxy.com), a wonderful little tool for watching network activity. (It’s also incredibly helpful when diagnosing API traffic, though the initial configuration can admittedly be a little daunting the first time you set it up.) That is, unfortunately, a paid tool, though. You can also use Instruments’ “Points of Interest” tool, which comes as part of Xcode, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39416673/1271826), though you need to sprinkle `os_signpost` calls before and after the network request.

Comment: Also, in Xcode’s Instruments, you can use the “Network” template, which includes the “HTTP Traffic” instrument, which will show you a bar graph of how many concurrent network requests you have running across time, which conveys the same basic network activity information, but in a slightly different layout. E.g. here is the Instruments output including “HTTP Traffic” and the “Points of Interest” (obviously having added the `os_signpost` calls to mark the `.begin` and `.end` of each network request). https://i.stack.imgur.com/xR4Ii.png

Comment: This may be better as a separate question, but how would you go about adding more tasks once the first set of tasks was already underway? Say in the middle of those 20 operations, another function wants to add 10 more, or something like that?

Comment: @RL2000 - You can use [`AsyncChannel`](https://github.com/apple/swift-async-algorithms/blob/main/Sources/AsyncAlgorithms/AsyncAlgorithms.docc/Guides/Channel.md) from [Swift Async Algorithms](https://github.com/apple/swift-async-algorithms). E.g., see example in https://stackoverflow.com/a/73072799/1271826 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/75730483/1271826.