# Implementing a custom asynchronous sequence in Swift

Tags: swift, asynchronous, async-await, asyncsequence

Imagine I want to create a function that, given an array of numbers, computes the square, cube, and fourth power of each number in an asynchronous fashion and returns a flattened, asynchronous sequence of all these results.

So, for example, for the input array `[2, 3, 4]`, it should return an `AsyncSequence` instance yielding the elements `[4, 8, 16, 9, 27, 81, 16, 64, 256]`.

Then let's say, instead of computing `x^2, x^3, x^4`, I would like it to compute `x, x^2, x^3, ..., x^k` where `k` is sort of a random integer that can be different for every x and is not known beforehand (its value comes to be known only as the powers are being computed). How would I implement such a pattern?

Comment: Basically it's kind of the same of creating your own type conforming to Sequence: you ought make it conform to AsyncSequence, hence it must provide an async iterator via makeAsyncIterator. In your case I think you could just use an AsyncStream internally for the async iterator since it won't throw any error.

Comment: The *As a next step* part is really a second question with a separate answer. Good SO questions should be focused on one thing -- consider removing that and posting it as its own question.

Comment: Do not edit a question include its own answer. If you can answer your own question, you are free to do so: as an Answer, in the Answer field. But you cannot do that now, because this question is closed. Do not edit the question purely as a way to work around the rules. Edit it solely to _improve the question._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot to [Rob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1271826/rob) for providing the basic idea on how to implement something like this.

I wrote it in the following way:

```swift
func powers(of numbers: [Int]) -> AsyncStream<Int> {
    return AsyncStream<Int> { continuation in
        Task {
            for number in numbers {
                for await power in Powers(of: number) {
                    continuation.yield(power)
                }
            }
            continuation.finish()
        }
    }
}

struct Powers: AsyncSequence {
    init(of base: Int) {
        self.base = base
    }
    
    func makeAsyncIterator() -> PowersIterator {
        return PowersIterator(base: self.base)
    }
    
    let base: Int
    typealias Element = Int
}

struct PowersIterator: AsyncIteratorProtocol {
    mutating func next() async -> Int? {
        if !self.shouldFinish() {
            try? await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 1_000_000_000)
            defer {
                self.exponent += 1
            }
            return power(self.base, self.exponent)
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
    
    private func shouldFinish() -> Bool {
        return Int.random(in: 1...10) == 1
    }
    
    private func power(_ base: Int, _ exponent: UInt) -> Int {
        return (0..<exponent).reduce(1) { power, _ in power * base }
    }
    
    var exponent = UInt(1)
    let base: Int
}
```

It can be invoked using this code:

```swift
Task {
    let numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    for await power in powers(of: numbers) {
        print(power, terminator: " ")
    }
}
```

Possible output:

```
1 1 1 2 4 8 16 32 64 3 9 27 4 16 64 256 5 25 125 625 3125 15625
```

The solution is a little more complex than it ought to be. But that's of course because I actually wanted to compute something that would really need to be computed asynchronously and has the same computational structure as this example. That is also the reason for why I created a separate async sequence for computing the powers.

If this helps anyone out, I'll be glad.

Answer (score 1):

An `AsyncStream` could do the job. E.g., given an array of integers, `values`, the asynchronous sequence would be:

```swift
let stream = AsyncStream<Int> { continuation in
    Task.detached {
        for value in values {
            var result = value
            for _ in 1 ..< n {
                result *= value
                continuation.yield(result)
            }
        }

        continuation.finish()
    }
}
```

But this calculation of *x², x³,* ..., *xⁿ* for each element in the input array might not be a good candidate for an asynchronous sequence. Each subsequent value can be calculated nearly instantaneously (just multiplying the previously emitted value by *x*) and, as such, should probably just be a standard, synchronous sequence.

Generally, asynchronous sequences should be those that are sufficiently slow to justify moving it into the background or otherwise has results that are emitted asynchronously over time.

Comment: FWIW, if your question was how to make your own AsyncSequence rather than just using AsyncStream, see [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72408350/1271826). WWDC 2021 video [Meet AsyncSequence](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10058/) is a good primer.

Comment: Or [SE-0298 - Async/Await: Sequences](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0298-asyncsequence.md).