# Testing parallel execution with structured concurrency

Tags: swift, concurrency, xctest

I’m testing code that uses an actor, and I’d like to test that I’m properly handling concurrent access and reentrancy. One of my usual approaches would be to use `DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform` to fire off a bunch of requests from different threads, and ensure my values resolve as expected. However, since the actor uses structured concurrency, I’m not sure how to actually wait for the tasks to complete.

What I’d like to do is something like:

```swift
let iterationCount = 100
let allTasksComplete = expectation(description: "allTasksComplete")
allTasksComplete.expectedFulfillmentCount = iterationCount
DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: iterationCount) { _ in
    Task {
        // Do some async work here, and assert
        allTasksComplete.fulfill()
    }
}
wait(for: [allTasksComplete], timeout: 1.0)
```

However the timeout for the `allTasksComplete` expectation expires every time, regardless of whether the iteration count is 1 or 100, and regardless of the length of the timeout. I’m assuming this has something to do with the fact that mixing structured and DispatchQueue-style concurrency is a no-no?

How can I properly test concurrent access — specifically how can I guarantee that the actor is accessed from different threads, and wait for the test to complete until all expectations are fulfilled?

Comment: Regarding achieving concurrent execution, rather than GCD’s `concurrentPerform`, we would use a task group (e.g., `withTaskGroup`).

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware that `TaskGroup` would do parallelism. I know there's no way to guarantee that tasks in a `TaskGroup` are fired from different threads; is there a way to check that it does happen? I can't use `Thread.current`, and `NSLog` messages from inside the task all report the same invoking thread. (It's also possible I'm just going about this testing the wrong way and should isolate my components differently...)

Comment: I've also edited my question title to more accurately reflect my ask, which is around testing parallel execution. If you would like to add your `TaskGroup` suggestion as an answer I'm happy to accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A few observations:

1. When testing Swift concurrency, we no longer need to rely upon expectations. We can just mark our tests as `async` methods. See [Asynchronous Tests and Expectations](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/asynchronous_tests_and_expectations/). Here is an async test adapted from that example:

   ```swift
   func testDownloadWebDataWithConcurrency() async throws {
       let url = try XCTUnwrap(URL(string: "https://apple.com"), "Expected valid URL.")

       let (_, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)

       let httpResponse = try XCTUnwrap(response as? HTTPURLResponse, "Expected an HTTPURLResponse.")
       XCTAssertEqual(httpResponse.statusCode, 200, "Expected a 200 OK response.")
   }
   ```
2. FWIW, while we can now use `async` tests when testing Swift concurrency, we still can use expectations:

   ```swift
   func testWithExpectation() {
       let iterations = 100
       let experiment = ExperimentActor()

       let e = self.expectation(description: #function)
       e.expectedFulfillmentCount = iterations

       for i in 0 ..< iterations {
           Task.detached {
               let result = await experiment.reentrantCalculation(i)
               let success = await experiment.isAcceptable(result)
               XCTAssert(success, "Incorrect value")
               e.fulfill()
           }
       }

       wait(for: [e], timeout: 10)
   }
   ```
3. You said:

   > However the timeout for the `allTasksComplete` expectation expires every time, regardless of whether the iteration count is 1 or 100, and regardless of the length of the timeout.

   We cannot comment without seeing a reproducible example of the code replaced with the comment “Do some async work here, and assert”. We do not need to see your actual implementation, but rather construct the simplest possible example that manifests the behavior you describe. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

   I personally suspect that you have some other, unrelated deadlock. E.g., given that `concurrentPerform` blocks the thread from which you call it, maybe you are doing something that requires the blocked thread. Also, be careful with `Task { ... }`, which runs the task on the current actor, so if you are doing something slow and synchronous inside there, that could cause problems. We might use detached tasks, instead.

   In short, we cannot diagnose the issue without a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
4. As a more general observation, one should be wary about mixing GCD (or semaphores or long-lived locks or whatever) with Swift concurrency, because the latter uses a cooperative thread pool, which relies upon assumptions about its threads being able to make forward progress. But if you have GCD API blocking threads, those assumptions may no longer be valid. It may not the source of the problem here, but I mention it as a cautionary note.
5. As an aside, `concurrentPerform` (which constrains the degree of parallelism) only makes sense if the work being executed runs synchronously. Using `concurrentPerform` to launch a series of asynchronous tasks will not constrain the concurrency at all. (The cooperative thread pool may, but `concurrentPerform` will not.)

   So, for example, if we wanted to test a bunch of calculations in parallel, rather than `concurrentPerform`, we might use a `TaskGroup`:

   ```swift
   func testWithStructuredConcurrency() async {
       let iterations = 100
       let experiment = ExperimentActor()

       await withTaskGroup(of: Void.self) { group in
           for i in 0 ..< iterations {
               group.addTask {
                   let result = await experiment.reentrantCalculation(i)
                   let success = await experiment.isAcceptable(result)
                   XCTAssert(success, "Incorrect value")
               }
           }
       }

       let count = await experiment.count
       XCTAssertEqual(count, iterations)
   }
   ```
6. Now if you wanted to verify concurrent execution within an app, normally I would just profile the app (not unit tests) with Instruments, and either watch intervals in the “Points of Interest” tool or look at the new “Swift Tasks” tool described in WWDC 2022’s [Visualize and optimize Swift concurrency](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/110350/) video. E.g., here I have launched forty tasks and I can see that my device runs six at a time:

   [image]

   See [Alternative to DTSendSignalFlag to identify key events in Instruments?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19017843/1271826) for references about the “Points of Interest” tool.
7. If you really wanted to write a unit test to confirm concurrency, you could theoretically keep track of your own counters, e.g.,

   ```swift
   final class MyAppTests: XCTestCase {
       func testWithStructuredConcurrency() async {
           let iterations = 100
           let experiment = ExperimentActor()

           await withTaskGroup(of: Void.self) { group in
               for i in 0 ..< iterations {
                   group.addTask {
                       let result = await experiment.reentrantCalculation(i)
                       let success = await experiment.isAcceptable(result)
                       XCTAssert(success, "Incorrect value")
                   }
               }
           }

           let count = await experiment.count
           XCTAssertEqual(count, iterations, "Correct count")

           let degreeOfConcurrency = await experiment.maxDegreeOfConcurrency
           XCTAssertGreaterThan(degreeOfConcurrency, 1, "No concurrency")
       }
   }
   ```

   Where:

   ```swift
   actor ExperimentActor {
       var degreeOfConcurrency = 0
       var maxDegreeOfConcurrency = 0
       var count = 0

       /// Calculate pi with Leibniz series
       ///
       /// Note: I am awaiting a detached task so that I can manifest actor reentrancy.

       func reentrantCalculation(_ index: Int, decimalPlaces: Int = 8) async -> Double {
           let task = Task.detached {
               logger.log("starting \(index)")                   // I wouldn’t generally log in a unit test, but it’s a quick visual confirmation that I’m enjoying parallel execution
               await self.increaseConcurrencyCount()

               let threshold = pow(0.1, Double(decimalPlaces))
               var isPositive = true
               var denominator: Double = 1
               var result: Double = 0
               var increment: Double

               repeat {
                   increment = 4 / denominator
                   if isPositive {
                       result += increment
                   } else {
                       result -= increment
                   }
                   isPositive.toggle()
                   denominator += 2
               } while increment >= threshold

               logger.log("finished \(index)")
               await self.decreaseConcurrencyCount()

               return result
           }

           count += 1

           return await task.value
       }

       func increaseConcurrencyCount() {
           degreeOfConcurrency += 1
           if degreeOfConcurrency > maxDegreeOfConcurrency { maxDegreeOfConcurrency = degreeOfConcurrency}
       }

       func decreaseConcurrencyCount() {
           degreeOfConcurrency -= 1
       }

       func isAcceptable(_ result: Double) -> Bool {
           return abs(.pi - result) < 0.0001
       }
   }
   ```
8. Please note that if testing/running on simulator, the cooperative thread pool is somewhat constrained, not exhibiting the same degree of concurrency as you will see on an actual device.
9. Also note that if you are testing whether a particular test is exhibiting parallel execution, you might want to disable the parallel execution of tests, themselves, so that other tests do not tie up your cores, preventing any given particular test from enjoying parallel execution.

   [image]

Comment: I'm using Task+expectation extensively in testing async code specifically for the timeouts. If your async code never returns, your test will hang indefinitely (or at least minutes if you're using testplans with timeouts). With expectations, not only can the timeout be much faster, but it gives you a clear error. I've been really surprised how well XCTest works with async + expectations. (As you note, I wouldn't add GCD here; I'd just spawn a bunch of Tasks to check reentrancy, and trust structured concurrency to handle parallelism correctly.)