# Points of interest not showing in Xcode Instruments

Tags: xcode, profiling, xcode-instruments

'Points of interest' are not showing in Xcode. What are possible reasons for this?

Sample (followed from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39416673/1766265)):

```
let pointsOfInterest = OSLog(subsystem: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!, category: .pointsOfInterest)
os_signpost(.event, log: pointsOfInterest, name: "Done", "All done")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I personally had this when I had the environment variable `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE` set at `disable`.

In a previous version, Xcode logged way too much which is why this setting was still active in my case.

When I unchecked this, the points of interest showed up again.

[image: Uncheck OS_ACTIVITY_MODE]

[image]