# In Swift, why is a custom serial queue with a global queue as its target not executed concurrently?

Tags: swift, serialization, concurrency, queue, grand-central-dispatch

This is my first question here, so please be nice. 
I struggle to understand the dynamics around a queue's target in Swift:

1. I have read that a custom queue inherits the behaviour of its target queue.
2. In the example below, `concurrentQueue` has its attribute set to `.concurrent`.
3. But because its target queue is `DispatchQueue.main`, which is serial by definition, `concurrentQueue` is getting executed serially:

   ```swift
   let concurrentQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "concurrentQueue",
                                       attributes: .concurrent,
                                       target: DispatchQueue.main)

   concurrentQueue.async {
       for i in 1...5 {
           print(i)
       }
   }

   concurrentQueue.async {
       for i in 6...10 {
           print(i)
       }
   }
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   1
   2
   3
   4
   5
   6
   7
   8
   9
   10
   ```
4. Conversely, if I have a custom serial queue which has a global queue as its target, which is concurrent by definition, I would my custom serial queue expect to get executed concurrently.
5. However, my custom serial queue is still getting executed serially. Why is that?

**PROBLEM STATEMENT:**

7. Here, `serialQueue` has not attribute defined which makes it a serial queue.
8. Because it has a concurrent queue `DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background)` as its target, I would expect it to get executed concurrently.
9. However, the output is still serial.

   ```swift
   let serialQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "serialQueue", target: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background))

   serialQueue.async {
       for i in 1...5 {
           print(i)
       }
   }

   serialQueue.async {
       for i in 6...10 {
           print(i)
       }
   }
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   1
   2
   3
   4
   5
   6
   7
   8
   9
   10
   ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior you describe is correct.

- If you create a private serial queue, regardless of its target, it will perform the tasks serially. The concurrent nature of the target queue does not affect the serial nature of your private queue.
- If you create a private concurrent queue, if the target is serial, your private queue will be constrained to serial behavior of the underlying target queue.

---

This begs the question of what is the purpose of a target queue.

A good example would be an “exclusion queue”. See WWDC 2017 video [Modernizing Grand Central Dispatch Usage](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/706/?time=1241). The idea is that you might have two separate serial queues, but you want them to run exclusively of each other, so you would create yet another serial queue, and use that as the target for the other two. It avoids unnecessary context switches, ensures serial behaviors across multiple queues, etc. See that video for more information.

---

Loosely related, see the `setTarget(_:)` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchobject/1452989-settarget), which offers a little context for targets:

> The target queue defines where blocks run, but it doesn't change the semantics of the current queue. Blocks submitted to a serial queue still execute serially, even if the underlying target queue is concurrent. In addition, you can't create concurrency where none exists. If a queue and its target queue are both serial, submitting blocks to both queues doesn't cause those blocks to run concurrently. The blocks still run serially in the order the target queue receives them.

---

By the way, five iterations may go quickly enough that you may not see parallel execution, even with a concurrent queue:

```swift
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "concurrentQueue", attributes: .concurrent)

queue.async {
    for i in 1...5 {
        print(i)
    }
}

queue.async {
    for i in 6...10 {
        print(i)
    }
}
```

That will often still misleadingly lead you to conclude that there is still serial execution:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

It actually is concurrent, but the first block finishes before the second one gets a chance to start!

You may have to introduce a little delay to manifest the concurrent execution. While you should practically never `Thread.sleep` in real code, for illustrative purposes, it slows it down enough to demonstrate the concurrent execution:

```swift
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "concurrentQueue", attributes: .concurrent)

queue.async {
    for i in 1...5 {
        print(i)
        Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 1)
    }
}

queue.async {
    for i in 6...10 {
        print(i)
        Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 1)
    }
}
```

That yields:

```
1
6
7
2
8
3
4
9
5
10
```

Or, if you are ambitious, you can use “Instruments” » “Time Profiler” with the following code:

```swift
import os.log

let poi = OSLog(subsystem: "Demo", category: .pointsOfInterest)
```

And then:

```swift
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "concurrentQueue", attributes: .concurrent)

queue.async {
    for i in 1...5 {
        let id = OSSignpostID(log: poi)
        os_signpost(.begin, log: poi, name: "first", signpostID: id, "Start %d", i)
        print(i)
        Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 1)
        os_signpost(.end, log: poi, name: "first", signpostID: id, "End %d", i)
    }
}

queue.async {
    for i in 6...10 {
        let id = OSSignpostID(log: poi)
        os_signpost(.begin, log: poi, name: "second", signpostID: id, "Start %d", i)
        print(i)
        Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 1)
        os_signpost(.end, log: poi, name: "second", signpostID: id, "End %d", i)
    }
}
```

And you can visually see the parallel execution if you use Xcode’s “Product” » “Profile” » “Time Profiler”:

[image]

For more information see [How to identify key events in Xcode Instruments?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19017843/1271826)

But, again, avoid `Thread.sleep`, but just make sure you are doing enough in the loop to manifest the parallel execution.

Comment: Many thanks for you explanation Rob! This makes sense and is very helpful. I was expecting such kind of behaviour but I simply could not find it anywhere. Let me know if you have any tips about how to look things up like that (eg. documentation or other websites)

Comment: I don't think I’ve got any silver bullets for that. Apple’s documentation on GCD is inconsistent. Worse, Apple‘s Swift GCD documentation still has Objective-C syntax littered throughout. I guess I’d suggest Stack Overflow search for “[gcd] target queue” or google “how to use gcd target queue”. Both are imperfect, though. For this particular one, I searched https://developer.apple.com for “target queue” and found that `setTarget` documentation that I just added to my answer.

Comment: This fantastic feedback though Rob! Many many thanks for that. I am a new developer and literally took Apple's documentation as the holy source of truth. Great to be told that! Describing how you researched this problem is more than just useful. Many thanks again and greetings to LA.