# What could cause different output for the same code?

Tags: swift, xcode, grand-central-dispatch, swift-playground

Why does this piece of code produce different output when run in Xcode and Swift Playground?

```swift
for i in 0...10 {
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        DispatchQueue.global().sync {
            print("Print1",i)
        }
        print("Print2",i)
    }
}
```

Swift Playground Output:

```
Print1 0
Print1 1
Print1 4
Print1 2
Print1 5
Print1 3
Print1 7
Print1 6
Print1 8
Print1 9
Print1 10
Print2 10
Print2 4
Print2 2
Print2 6
Print2 1
Print2 3
Print2 8
Print2 5
Print2 7
Print2 0
Print2 9
```

Xcode output:

```
Print1 0
Print2 0
Print1 2
Print1 3
Print1 4
Print2 4
Print1 6
Print2 6
Print1 8
Print2 8
Print1 10
Print2 10
Print2 2
Print2 3
Print1 5
Print2 5
Print1 9
Print2 9
Print1 7
Print2 7
Print1 1
Print2 1
```

I ran it on different platforms, and the result was the same.

Comment: Think this happens since you are using Dispatch Queue. Generally, it will dispatch the task to the global queue and execute them concurrently.  You can try using a serial queue if you want to print in the specific orders. First, define the serial queue and then you can try using - serialQueue.async{} . 
You can also refer - https://medium.com/@almalehdev/concurrency-visualized-part-2-serial-vs-concurrent-fd04e32c20a9 
Please try, thank you

Comment: The main problem here that in Swift Playground the output always sorted (print1 0, print1 1, print1 2..., print2 0 ...) whereas in Xcode it's always random

Comment: @Nick Swift playgrounds probably do more locking (e.g. for rendering previews on the right bar), and accidentally synchronize this code. In "real code" you need to prevent data races yourself, either by not designing code paths to be racey in the first place, or by synchronizing it yourself.

Comment: Your sample output shows the output being in semi-random order for both the Swift Playground and the app version. The swift playground output you list shows your print1 output as 0,  1,  4,  2,  5,  3,  7,  6,  8,  9, 10 and your print2 output as 10, 4,  2,  6,  1,  3,  8,  5,  7,  0,  9.

Comment: @DuncanC – I believe the question was not about the randomized 0…10 order, but rather that in the playground, all of the `sync` output (the “Print1” output) came out before any of the “Print2” output start coming out.

Comment: Oh, gotcha. I don't have a good answer for that.

Answer (score 1):

Dispatches to a concurrent queue can introduce races. Unfortunately, Playgrounds introduce sufficient overhead to lead one to incorrect conclusions.

For example, try the following in a playground, where we fetch the queue only once, but otherwise follow the pattern of your original example:

```swift
let queue = DispatchQueue.global()
for i in 0...10 {
    queue.async {
        queue.sync {
            print("Print1",i)
        }
        print("Print2",i)
    }
}
```

In my Playground, I now see:

```
Print1 0
Print1 1
Print2 0
Print1 2
Print1 3
Print2 1
Print1 4
Print2 3
Print1 5
Print2 4
Print1 6
Print2 5
Print1 7
Print2 6
Print1 8
Print2 7
Print1 9
Print2 8
Print1 10
Print2 9
Print2 10
Print2 2
```

That more closely resembles the behavior we see in Xcode. (It leads me to believe, to my surprise, that fetching the global queue is sufficiently slow in a Playground to alter the results.) Your results may vary, but you can see that the behavior can vary as a result of the most minor changes, leading to very different conclusions.

Bottom line, avoid using Playgrounds to draw conclusions about specific performance related behaviors in parallel execution. Races (especially when dispatching work items that, themselves, execute so quickly) are hard to manifest consistently. The overhead in Playgrounds can artificially skew the results.

---

For what it is worth, I prefer to use Instruments (see [How to identify key events in Xcode Instruments?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19017843/1271826)) to visually illustrate what is really going on. I also replace the simple `print` statements with something that is slow enough to actually manifest parallel execution. In the below, I replaced the `print` statements with a loop that spins on the CPU for one second. As a result, we can see a timeline that shows what really happens in parallel, and what doesn’t. FWIW, I limited this to six iterations, as to not make it too confusing:

[image]

The green intervals are where “Print1” was (inside the `sync` call), the orange intervals are where “Print2” was (after the `sync` call), and the purple intervals are the `async` call (where we had both “Print1” and “Print2” for that respective iteration). Because “Print1” and “Print2” have been replaced with spinning loops, we can now clearly see where there is concurrency, and where there are dependencies.

There are really a limited number of conclusions that can be drawn:

1. Because the simple `print` statements have been replaced with something that takes a little longer, we mitigate aspects of the races between the “Print1” of one iteration and the “Print2” of other iterations;
2. The six individual iterations run in parallel with respect to each other (because we are using a global queue, which is a concurrent queue); and
3. Each “Print2” does not start until its respective “Print1” finishes (because the latter was done synchronously).

Beyond that (e.g., in what order the six parallel iterations actually run), we cannot say much.